# How may I program the following with Python?

Tags: programming, python

please help me do the following with python

1. create a directory - say - dir_01.
2. open a file - say - file_01 and write "hello - 01" into that file and    close the file.
3. run the command (on a Linux system) say :  command file_01
4. wait for the above command ( command file_01 ) to complete. for example this command is complete if a file "product_01.txt" is generated
5. go to step 1

thank you so much for your help.

Comment: This site is for TeX and friends. If the question is how to do that from inside TeX, you should make it clear. Otherwise it's off topic, I'm afraid.

Comment: This is a question for [so].